# Caption under image in wordpress not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, caption

I am using WordPress for my website and I am trying to add a caption under this [image](http://socialpsychstudies.com/). I tried captioning it when uploading it in media and have also used the tag "figcaption" as html for the frontpage but it doesn't work.
I also tried to add text on the frontpage footer but since footer is global, it changes the footer throughout the website.
How can I add a caption under the image?

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work": 1) Is caption in the DB?  (see post excerpt , or check it shows up when you edit the media), 2) when you add media to a post, does the caption show up?  3)  when you have added the media with caption to a post and show the 'text' view in edit post, is it showing the [caption shortcode ?  and the closing /caption] with the caption text right before?, and if yes to all the above, 5) when you view source of the html page, is the <figcaption there?  if yes, then 6) check if the css is hiding the caption (use inspect element in browser or change to default theme.)

Comment: Its actually a background image but when I upload the media with caption, the caption does not appear. Is it because its a background image? The view source does not have <figcaption. Is there any other way to give image credits without changing the theme for e.g. adjusting the footer only on the first page or installing a plug-in?

Comment: Css does not have provision for text in a background image specification.   As for adding visible text to the html of a wordpress site, there are many many ways, starting with just adding text to the page.  maybe a text widget to the footer?